# В роутах не передан параметр

Tags: laravel-5.6

> FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>   Too few arguments to function  App\Http\Controllers\admin\adminProductsController::editProduct(), 0 passed and еxactly 1 expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Решение:*

Нужно прописать параметр `{id}` в роуте на контроллер:

```
Route::get('admin/editProduct/**{id}**', 'admin\adminProductsController@editProduct')->name('adminEditProduct');
```